# Moving repetitive lines of code outside of a class for efficiency

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I've made a module and in it I have two classes as follow:

```
class Class_1:

    def get_table(loc):
        
        ocr_xml = AbbyyXML(loc)
        xml_doc = XMLDoc(ocr_xml)
        # and some stuff
        return abc

class Class_2: 

    def get_table(loc):
        
        ocr_xml = AbbyyXML(loc)
        xml_doc = XMLDoc(ocr_xml)
        # and some stuff
         return xyz
```

The idea is to feed in some .xml document and using the `get_table()` methods do some operations.
Both classes work just fine and I apply them as follow:

```
from my_module import *
def incoming(client_name, loc):
    act = client_name.get_table(loc)
    return act
```

where `client_name` can be `Class_1` or `Class_2`. My question is about the efficiency of this code, as you can see `get_table()` method has a variable called `loc` which is the location of the .xml file. I wonder if I can move the

```
ocr_xml = AbbyyXML(loc)
xml_doc = XMLDoc(ocr_xml)
```

outside the class to avoid repetition? So far given that methods in both classes have variable loc, I failed to do this and use inheritance.

Comment: why dont you make a super class and put that part into a method which the sub classes can call?

Comment: @h11 I have not worked with super classes so far, could you please elaborate more with a pseudo code?

Comment: before creating the superclass or subclass, you need to check that `get_table` depend on class variable or not, if it is indepependent, then the i suggest to use a seperate function only, if it is dependent on some of the class variable , then no need to create seperate class or inheritance

Answer (score -1):

I haven't actually used python but this is more a general design question.

had a brief look online and have wrote the following (it may not compile)

This is the site i used for reference

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp

```
class SuperClass:
  def __init__(self):

  // put your method in here
  def readFiles(self):
    // read files and write to fields in this class
```

```
class Class_1(SuperClass):

    def get_table(loc):
        self.readFiles()
        # and some stuff
        return abc

class Class_2(SuperClass): 

    def get_table(loc):
        self.readFiles()
        
        # and some stuff
         return xyz
```